# Issues in Ordering up table values in hive

Tags: sql, hive, sql-order-by

I would like to order the values of my table in specific manner.

I have a source table(TestTable) with below data

```
groupId,Name,subjectCode,PA
1,LEADER,T,67
1,Prem,P,67
1,Prem,T,89
1,Anjali,T,124
1,LEADER,P,234
1,Anjali,P,234
1,Anjali,NP,45
1,Prem,NP,23
1,LEADER,NP,123
```

and my expected results for new table TestSort is

```
1,LEADER,NP,123
1,LEADER,P,234
1,LEADER,T,67
1,Anjali,NP,45
1,Anjali,P,234
1,Anjali,T,124
1,Prem,NP,23
1,Prem,P,67
1,Prem,T,89
```

I need to order 1st three columns in asc and also I have to place the leader record at the top it self.

I tried to do the same ,But I am not getting  the results as expected

> insert overwrite table TestSort  select * from TestTable order by
>   groupId asc,Name asc,subjectCode asc;

The result what I get is

```
groupId,Name,subjectCode,PA
1,LEADER,T,67
1,LEADER,NP,123
1,Anjali,NP,45
1,Anjali,P,234
1,LEADER,P,234
1,Anjali,T,124
1,Prem,T,89
1,Prem,NP,23
1,Prem,P,67
```

Am I doing anything wrong somewhere.

**TRAIL 1**

```
  insert overwrite table TestSort select * from TestTable 
order by 
  case when name = 'LEADER' then '0' else '1' end, 
  groupid, 
  name,
  subjectcode;;
    select * from TestSort;
```

The result for above query is

```
    groupId,Name,subjectCode,PA
1,Anjali,NP,45
1,LEADER,T,67
1,Prem,T,89
1,Prem,P,67
1,LEADER,NP,123
1,Prem,NP,23
1,Anjali,T,124
1,Anjali,P,234
1,LEADER,P,234
```

My expectation is to insert values into a new table TestSort. Select query gives me the expected result, but once I insert the values into TestSort,the order is getting changed.

Comment: Select without order by returns dataset unordered by definition. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54542826/2700344 and this also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47416027/2700344

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will work

```
select *, case when Name = 'LEADER' then '1' else '0' end as rank from Test order by rank desc, groupId, Name ,subjectCode asc;
```

Comment: WIth the above equation I am able to get the results. But once I insert it back to my destination table without rank..again the records are getting reordered. I am updating the question with the trail case of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition directly in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select * from test 
order by 
  case when name = 'LEADER' then '0' else '1' end, 
  groupid, 
  name,
  subjectcode;
```

Comment: yes it works during select but once I insert it to my destination table..the order goes. insert overwrite table TestSort select * from test 
order by 
  case when name = 'LEADER' then '0' else '1' end, 
  groupid, 
  name,
  subjectcode;

Comment: There is no order inside a table. You have to fetch the rows of the table again by using ORDER BY.