# Hive Query: How to use group by with rank?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I have a table like below

```
year                            int                                                                                                                   
month                           int                                                                                                                   
symbol                          string                                                                                                                
company_name                    string                                                                                                                
sector                          string                                                                                                                
sub_industry                    string                                                                                                                
state                           string                                                                                                                
avg_open                        double                                                                                                                
avg_close                       double                                                                                                                
avg_low                         double                                                                                                                
avg_high                        double                                                                                                                
avg_volume                      double
```

The field starting with `avg_` refers to the average value in a month for a year. I need to find for each sector the year in which average of `avg_close` is the lowest.

I tried to do something like below

```
SELECT sector, year FROM
  (
    SELECT sector, year, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s2.yearly_avg_close) AS RANK FROM
      ( SELECT year,sector, AVG(avg_close) AS yearly_avg_close FROM stock_summary GROUP BY sector, year) s2
  ) s1 
WHERE
  s1.RANK = 1;
```

But this is printing just one sector and year like below

```
Telecommunications Services     2010
```

I am new to hive and playing around with some toy schemas. Can someone let me know what should be the correct way of solving this?

Hive Version - 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `sector` into the `partition by` in the `rank()` function:

```
SELECT sector, year, RANK() OVER (partition by sector ORDER BY s2.yearly_avg_close) AS RANK
```

Add `year` as well if you need rank per each `sector` and `year`

Read also this explanation how rank works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909947/2700344