# Hive giving different results for same query and same data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I have following data in my table.

[image]

Running below query through script and giving me different results every time when I execute.  For example rptind for id 2, some times it gives 'P' and some times its 'n'. Not sure why it is changing the value for this rptind.

if I execute manually, I see same results always.

```
select id,eff_dt,ind,rptind,row_number() over 
(partition by id order by(case when ind="ok" then 1 when ind="no" then 2 when ind="not" then 3 end)) 
as rnk from tmp1 order by id;
```

Not understanding why it is behaving like this. Can someone suggest what might be the cause of this issue.

Thank you, Babu

Comment: Non-deterministic behavior explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909947/2700344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...some times it gives 'P' and some times its 'n'

The order that you defined by:

```
case when ind="ok" then 1 when ind="no" then 2 when ind="not" then 3 end
```

will sort the rows by `ind`, but if there are 2 rows for the same `id` with `ind="ok"` and different `rptind`s `'p'` and `'n'`, you did not define which one should be first.

So expand your ordering conditions by defining the sort order for `rptind` too, like:

```
select id, eff_dt, ind, rptind,
       row_number() over (
         partition by id 
         order by case ind when 'ok' then 1 when 'no' then 2 when 'not' then 3 end,
                  case rptind when 'p' then 1 when 'n' then 2 end 
       ) as rnk 
from tmp1 
order by id;
```

You can expand the sort order further, if needed, to include other columns.

Answer (score 1):

What value do you want?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You have ties in the `order by` conditions, so `row_number()` can -- and does -- enumerate those ties differently.  For example:

```
id   eff_dt       ind   rpt_ind   
 2   2020-07-20    ok      n
 2   2020-07-21    ok      p
```

The partitioning is on `id` so both these rows are in a partition.  The `order by` is based on `ind` and both have the same value.  Which is chosen *on a particular run* is arbitrary.  Remember:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so there is no ordering to fall back on.

You haven't specified the logic that you actually want.  The safest method is to include a unique identifier as the last key in the `order by`.  Usually, such a key is `id`, but that is clearly not the case here.  Perhaps `eff_dt` along with `id` is unique (as in the above example):

```
row_number() over (partition by id
                   order by (case when ind = 'ok' then 1 when ind = 'no' then 2 when ind = 'not' then 3 end),
                            eff_dt desc
                  )
```

As a final recourse, you could just use `rptind`, so you prioritize those values in the `row_number()`.